# R change column names, retain part of colnames

Tags: r

I have a df with colnames thus:

```
Resampled.Band.1..raster.bsq...404.502014.Nanometers.
...
Resampled.Band.74..raster.bsq...950.851990.Nanometers.
```

I want them like this:
`950.851990_nm`

With:

```
orig_names <- names(df)
new_name <- gsub("Resampled.Band.", "", orig_names)
```

and

```
new_name <- gsub(".Nanometers.", "_nm", new_name)
names(all_roi_rfl) <- new_name
```

I achieve part of what I want: to change the first and last parts of the colnames:
`1..raster.bsq...404.502014_nm`
I could repeat this to clean the colnames up most of the way.

But how do I deal with the part of the colnames that varies itself, the band number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the values that you want using regex and replace the column names.

```
x <- c('Resampled.Band.1..raster.bsq...404.502014.Nanometers.', 
       'Resampled.Band.74..raster.bsq...950.851990.Nanometers.')

sub('.*raster.bsq\\.+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.Nanometers\\.', '\\1_nm', x)
#[1] "404.502014_nm" "950.851990_nm"
```

This extracts number that occur between `"raster.bsq"` and `"Nanometers"` and appends `"_nm"` to extracted value.

In your case to replace column names it would be :

```
names(all_roi_rfl) <- sub('.*raster.bsq\\.+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.Nanometers\\.', '\\1_nm', names(all_roi_rfl))
```

Comment: thanks again, seems i don't get the syntax. now i have ''''"X745.971008.Nanometers"''' as name and can't figure out how to make it in same format as in OP! trying '''names(df) <- sub('X\\.+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.Nanometers\\.', '\\1_nm', names(df))'''. thanks in advance, also to @pyll

Comment: That would require a different regex. Can you ask that as a new question?

Answer (score 1):

A similar answer to Ronak's but using `gsub` instead.

First generate a dataframe...

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    Resampled.Band.1..raster.bsq...404.502014.Nanometers. = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
    Resampled.Band.74..raster.bsq...950.851990.Nanometers. = c('a', 'b', 'c', NA))
```

using `gsub` identify the string before and after the piece you want to extract

```
colnames(df) <- gsub(".*raster.bsq...(.+).Nanometers.", "\\1_nm", colnames(df))
```